# php code display code in browser

Tags: php, database, image

I am doing a project using my university web server where my httpdocs are stored.
Everything works fine including my other PHP scripts which connect to phpmyadmin database both posting and getting from the database. However when I put this script on the web server and try to access it the page outputs some of the PHP code and I cannot find out why. I am not seeing any open tags etc. The page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gallery</title>
<a href="index.html">Home</a><br />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
<?php
mysql_connect("XXXXXXX","XXXXX","XXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXXXX");
mysql_select_db("sql1103884");
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Images");
echo "<table>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";?> <img src="<?php echo $row["imagepath"]; ?>" height="100" width="100">        <? php echo "</td>";
echo "<td>"; echo $row["name"]; echo "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, question.  Why are you jumping in and out of PHP so much in your loop?  :P  You could be like `while(...) { ?> <tr><td><img src="<?= $row["imagepath"] ?>" height="100" width="100"></td><td><?= $row["name"] ?></td></tr> <? }` (with appropriate whitespace, of course :P).

Comment: BTW, -0.49 for using `mysql_query` in 2013.

Comment: Your university web server might not even support PHP. The server has to be configured to serve PHP....have you confirmed that the server does support PHP?

Comment: Yeah, it supports, part of the project criteria is to use PHP.

Comment: @AndrewStewart: What's the file name?

Comment: A good way to check if your server supports php and even dependencies is to create a new file and put: <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file extension  is not php then please change it to `.php` and second replace with below code. there is space between php opening tag like this `<? php`  so it should be `<?php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gallery</title>
<a href="index.html">Home</a><br />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
<?php
mysql_connect("XXXXXXX","XXXXX","XXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXXXX");
mysql_select_db("sql1103884");
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Images");
echo "<table>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";?> <img src="<?php echo $row["imagepath"]; ?>" height="100" width="100">        <?php echo "</td>";
echo "<td>"; echo $row["name"]; echo "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you change in the php/html source?

Comment: The only difference i'm noticing is a removal of a space between `<?` and `php` in the line that spits out the image tag.  Could be significant.  But whether this is the root problem depends mostly on whether the stuff after it is the only PHP code being spit out.

Comment: (BTW @Praveen: For a change so minor, you should mention what you changed.  Reading answers shouldn't involve a treasure hunt.)